# Set postfix to send email but not to receive them

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, g-suite

I'm using Google Apps to handle personal email addresses for my domain name, and I set up the DNS as Google suggests. All works fine.

Now since I need a SMTP to send emails from my e-commerce I installed Postfix on the server.
It works fine when I send emails to any email address but it doesn't send to the same domain name, so let's say my domain is example.com, I set postfix using example.com, if I try to reset a password using myaccount@example.com postfix doesn't send and instead reports on the mail.log

```
Sep 20 01:09:52 ip-10-54-26-162 postfix/pickup[6809]: B09A3415D8: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Sep 20 01:09:52 ip-10-54-26-162 postfix/cleanup[6854]: B09A3415D8: message-id=<20120920010952.B09A3415D8@ip-10-54-26-162.eu-west-1.compute.internal>
Sep 20 01:09:52 ip-10-54-26-162 postfix/qmgr[30978]: B09A3415D8: from=<www-data@example.com>, size=4234, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 20 01:09:52 ip-10-54-26-162 postfix/local[6856]: B09A3415D8: to=<myaccount@example.com>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "myaccount")
```

Of course it cannot find a local user "myaccount" since that account is on Google Apps...

How can I tell Postfix to send the email and do not search for a local user?

Answer (score 1):

This is called "Postfix as a null client" and is extensively documented on their homepage: http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#null_client

As you can see in the Url it even is one of the STANDARDS.

You are not allowed to tell Postfix to be responsible for `example.com` because it is not. Google is responsible for the domain.